# Javascript Mobile Redirect Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //deaktop = "m." + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
    if ($(window).width() < 989) {
        document.location = "m." + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
    }
</script>
```

### Outcome URL

http://abcdfav4.com/Grown-Ups/KickStarterCampaign/Risks-and-Challenges/m.abcdfav4.com/Grown-Ups/KickStarterCampaign/Risks-and-Challenges/Hi-Tech-Perspective.html

So my script seems to be getting the current URL then adding `"m." + window.location.host + window.location.pathname` to the end whereas I just want to go to `"m." + window.location.host + window.location.pathname`

Comment: document.location = "`http://`m." + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the [protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/protocol):

```
document.location = window.location.protocol + '//m.' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the 'http' protocol and, maybe, with the 'www' too.

Try this:

```
var url = window.location.protocol+"//m."+ window.location.href.replace('http://', '').replace('www.', '');

window.location.href = url;
```